# Error while pushing image to docker. Requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to push an image of my application to `dockerhub` but i keep getting this error:

```
requested access to the resource is denied.
```

I am already logged in with my credentials using docker login. My repository is public. I have tried everything it keeps giving me this error.

```
docker login
docker tag springmysqldockerswagger:latest vai/spring:myfirstimagepush
docker push vai/spring:myfirstimagepush
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the repository `vai/spring` created in your public docker hub account ?

Comment: yes...its vai/spring